# C++ header files in MS Visual Studio Error Message E0147

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

As a beginner programmer I'm learning the basics of C++ programming, including creation of header files. I'm following the professor's lecture on Youtube and recreated the same code structure to store class integers below.  I am receiving the following compile error message for the class line.

Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "int MyInteger::get() const"

```
#include<iostream>

class MyInteger
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:

void set(int);

int get() const;
};

void MyInteger::set(int a)
{
    i = a;
}

void MyInteger::get() const
{
return i;
};


int main() {

    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `void MyInteger::get() const`? A `void` function cannot return a value.

Comment: I didn't understand why he put the void function into the code.  I stripped the code and left it this way with no problem.                                                
    #include<iostream>

    class MyInteger
    {
    private:                                                                                                                       
        int i;
    public:
 int get() const;
    };


    int main() {
 
 std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

 std::cin.get();
    }

Comment: @GhostWaggon Probably he missed it. The function signature must be the same in the declaration and definition.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is from the editor and its stating that `int MyInteger::get() const` declaration is incompatible with the declaration in the class. Which is true because in the class your `get()` method is declared as,

```cpp
int get() const;
```

But in your definition, its return type is set to `void`,

```cpp
void MyInteger::get() const
{
    return i;
};
```

This is the error. To fix it, define the return type as `int`,

```cpp
int MyInteger::get() const
{
    return i;
} // You dont need a semicolon here.
```

**Additional:** 
There are 3 types of error messages in MSVC,

1. Errors starting with 'E' which states that its from the editor.
2. Errors starting with 'C' which states that its from the compiler (compile time).
3. Errors starting with 'L' which states that its from the linker.

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  This helps.